# Executing and testing stanford core nlp example

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I downloaded stanford core nlp packages and tried to test it on my machine.

Using command: `java -cp "*" -mx1g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentPipeline -file input.txt`

I got sentiment result in form of `positive` or `negative`. `input.txt` contains the sentence to be tested.

On more command: `java -cp stanford-corenlp-3.3.0.jar;stanford-corenlp-3.3.0-models.jar;xom.jar;joda-time.jar -Xmx600m edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse -file input.txt` when executed gives follwing lines :

```
H:\Drive E\Stanford\stanfor-corenlp-full-2013~>java -cp stanford-corenlp-3.3.0.j
ar;stanford-corenlp-3.3.0-models.jar;xom.jar;joda-time.jar -Xmx600m edu.stanford
.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse -file
input.txt
Adding annotator tokenize
Adding annotator ssplit
Adding annotator pos
Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3wo
rds/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [36.6 sec].
Adding annotator lemma
Adding annotator parse
Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCF
G.ser.gz ... done [13.7 sec].

Ready to process: 1 files, skipped 0, total 1
Processing file H:\Drive E\Stanford\stanfor-corenlp-full-2013~\input.txt ... wri
ting to H:\Drive E\Stanford\stanfor-corenlp-full-2013~\input.txt.xml {
  Annotating file H:\Drive E\Stanford\stanfor-corenlp-full-2013~\input.txt [13.6
81 seconds]
} [20.280 seconds]
Processed 1 documents
Skipped 0 documents, error annotating 0 documents
Annotation pipeline timing information:
PTBTokenizerAnnotator: 0.4 sec.
WordsToSentencesAnnotator: 0.0 sec.
POSTaggerAnnotator: 1.8 sec.
MorphaAnnotator: 2.2 sec.
ParserAnnotator: 9.1 sec.
TOTAL: 13.6 sec. for 10 tokens at 0.7 tokens/sec.
Pipeline setup: 58.2 sec.
Total time for StanfordCoreNLP pipeline: 79.6 sec.

H:\Drive E\Stanford\stanfor-corenlp-full-2013~>
```

Could understand. No informative result.

I got one example at : [stanford core nlp java output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832490/stanford-core-nlp-java-output)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import edu.stanford.nlp.io.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;

public class StanfordCoreNlpDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter out;
    if (args.length > 1) {
      out = new PrintWriter(args[1]);
    } else {
      out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
    }
    PrintWriter xmlOut = null;
    if (args.length > 2) {
      xmlOut = new PrintWriter(args[2]);
    }

    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP();
    Annotation annotation;
    if (args.length > 0) {
      annotation = new Annotation(IOUtils.slurpFileNoExceptions(args[0]));
    } else {
      annotation = new Annotation("Kosgi Santosh sent an email to Stanford University. He didn't get a reply.");
    }

    pipeline.annotate(annotation);
    pipeline.prettyPrint(annotation, out);
    if (xmlOut != null) {
      pipeline.xmlPrint(annotation, xmlOut);
    }
    // An Annotation is a Map and you can get and use the various analyses individually.
    // For instance, this gets the parse tree of the first sentence in the text.
    List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);
    if (sentences != null && sentences.size() > 0) {
      CoreMap sentence = sentences.get(0);
      Tree tree = sentence.get(TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation.class);
      out.println();
      out.println("The first sentence parsed is:");
      tree.pennPrint(out);
    }
  }

}
```

Tried to execute it in netbeans with including necessary library. But it always stuck in between or gives exception `Exception in thread “main” java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Thou I set the memory to be allocated in `property/run/VM box`

Any idea how can I run above java example using command line?

**I want to get sentiment score of the example**

**UPDATE**

output of :  `java -cp "*" -mx1g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentPipeline -file input.txt`

[image]

out put of: `java -cp stanford-corenlp-3.3.0.j
ar;stanford-corenlp-3.3.0-models.jar;xom.jar;joda-time.jar -Xmx600m edu.stanford
.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse -file
input.txt`

[image: Out of of above command]

Comment: What was produced in your one example that worked? (That is "H:\Drive E\Stanford\stanfor-corenlp-full-2013~\input.txt.xml")

Comment: @home: `OutOfMemoryError` I already searached and worked upon the solutions on web. Still same error persist

Comment: for out of memory try playing around with `-mx?g` configuration in the example command. `?` means GB of RAM allocated for to run the code. Increase, until succeed I'd say.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add the "sentiment" annotator to the list of annotators:

```
-annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse,sentiment
```

This will add a "sentiment" property to each sentence node in your XML.

Comment: I found the example, where not all 6 annotators used in order to execute sentiment analysis, but only 4. POS & Lemma are not included, how it can influence on the results? Example: https://blog.openshift.com/day-20-stanford-corenlp-performing-sentiment-analysis-of-twitter-using-java/

Answer (score 23):

You can do the following in your code:

```
String text = "I am feeling very sad and frustrated.";
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, parse, sentiment");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
<...>
Annotation annotation = pipeline.process(text);
List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);
for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
  String sentiment = sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentClass.class);
  System.out.println(sentiment + "\t" + sentence);
}
```

It will print the sentiment of the sentence and the sentence itself, e.g. "I am feeling very sad and frustrated.":

```
Negative    I am feeling very sad and frustrated.
```

Comment: Where are you passing the input sentence in the program?

Comment: Added to example Annotation annotation = pipeline.process(text);

Answer (score 3):

Per the example [here](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/code.html) you need to run the Sentiment Analysis.

```
java -cp "*" -mx5g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentPipeline -file input.txt
```

Apparently this is a memory expensive operation, it may not complete with only 1 gigabyte.
Then you can use the "Evaluation Tool"

```
java -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.Evaluate edu/stanford/nlp/models/sentiment/sentiment.ser.gz input.txt
```

Comment: Elliott: You right but I took `-mx1g` as per my system configuration, and in command line it worked also

Comment: DO you have experience of testing Stanford coreNLP sentiment part?

Comment: No, I have experience with a commercial sentiment engine and you've got sentiment scores there in that image.

Comment: I apologize! I am newbei to NLP. I dont find sentiment score in image, may be I am missing with convention. I appreciate if you can enlight it

Comment: Yep. That appears to be working about as well as I'd expect with random code found on the 'net.

Comment: thanks for it. I think it is entity level sentiment. It should give sentiment of entire text. And there must be it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42451/discussion-between-karimkhan-and-elliott-frisch)

Answer (score 2):

This is working fine for me -

Maven Dependencies :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.2</version>
            <classifier>models</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-parser</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Java Code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String text = "This World is an amazing place";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, parse, sentiment");
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

        Annotation annotation = pipeline.process(text);
        List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);
        for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
            String sentiment = sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentClass.class);
            System.out.println(sentiment + "\t" + sentence);
        }
    }
```

Results :

Very positive   This World is an amazing place