# How to use StanfordCoreNLP jar to conduct semantic analysis in a Java Map/Reduce Job?

Tags: java, eclipse, mapreduce, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am currently working on Capital Markets Modelling. I am storing the data from various data sources  i.e. Financial news using Impala.

I have stored this data using Impala in a table of the form `articleID,ArticleDATA`.

My next step is to conduct semantic analysis row-by-row, on all records.

I have been reading through these resources

[Executing and testing stanford core nlp example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359346/executing-and-testing-stanford-core-nlp-example)

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml

https://www.openshift.com/blogs/day-20-stanford-corenlp-performing-sentiment-analysis-of-twitter-using-java

http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/code.html

I am making a Map/Reduce job in Eclipse using Java and couldn't figure out how do I use the JAR to help me with the analysis.

P.S: I ran the command
 `java -cp "*" -mx1g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentPipeline -file input.txt`
on sample data and it worked but via command line. I want to know how to do it in eclipse, map/reduce.

The current output sentiment is in terms of Positive, Neutral, Negative but I need it as 1,0,-1. I guess that's easy to figure out, so not a priority here.!

I Am confused as how to go about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out.. So closing the question. Had to work with the Sentiment files in the JAR. Trial and Error. Then made a MApReduce job.