# How do I execute Stanford CoreNLP sentiment analysis within a Java Program?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I'm using Stanford CoreNLP with the following command line arguments

```
java -cp "*" -mx5g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentPipeline -file foo.txt
```

I obtain the results within the command prompt as well. How do I execute the same in Java?

I can import all the libraries present there but I don't know which function to execute specifically to get the sentiment analysis results. How do I execute the same programmatically?

Comment: Regarding [your previous closed question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298152/are-there-any-satellite-image-processing-libraries-for-java) and your `"It just sucks you're unwilling guide me on how to start."` comment -- this has nothing to do with anyone being "unwilling" but all to do with your question being off-topic for this site. Please go through the [help] and the [tour] so you can see what is on and off topic for this site, and so to avoid your potential future disappointment.

Comment: Could you guide me to at least know which is the right site for questions like this? Given this is an off topic question as well.

Comment: Seriously, the [help] and the [tour] will guide you best. But for that last question you were asking for a reference to outside resources, which again is off topic. Note that this is not a rule that I created, and not that I necessarily support, but when in Rome, I'm obliged to follow the Roman rules as are us all. Luck.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you execute Java code programmatically using an application programming interfece (API). Stanford CoreNLP offers a demo showing how to use the API. Here's what their [FAQ page](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp-faq.shtml) says:

> How do I use the API?
>
> A brief demo program included with the download will demonstrate how
>   to load the tool and start processing text. When using this demo
>   program, be sure to include all of the appropriate jar files in the
>   classpath.

When you start playing with the demo program, check SO for other questions  that have been asked before about running the Stanford CoreNLP demo, for example this one: [Executing and testing stanford core nlp example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359346/executing-and-testing-stanford-core-nlp-example)

Comment: Thanks, executed it. Works perfectly now.

Comment: You can accept the answer if it works for you. This way you will notify everyone that the answer is a solution to your problem.