# how to process a batch of text files through the Stanford NLP pipeline?

Tags: eclipse, stanford-nlp

I need to process a batch of text files through the Stanford NLP pipeline with the semantic graph as output. There is an example of the pipeline I found [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832490/stanford-core-nlp-java-output). I just changed the class name, put out "dcoref" from .props,  and fill it as a new class to the Core NLP project in Eclipse.  Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import edu.stanford.nlp.io.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;

  public class testpipeline {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter out;
    if (args.length > 1) {
      out = new PrintWriter(args[1]);
    } else {
      out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
    }
    PrintWriter xmlOut = null;
    if (args.length > 2) {
      xmlOut = new PrintWriter(args[2]);
    }

    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP();
    Annotation annotation;
    if (args.length > 0) {
      annotation = new Annotation(IOUtils.slurpFileNoExceptions(args[0]));
    } else {
      annotation = new Annotation("He didn't get a reply.");
    }

    pipeline.annotate(annotation);
    pipeline.prettyPrint(annotation, out);
    if (xmlOut != null) {
      pipeline.xmlPrint(annotation, xmlOut);
    }
    // An Annotation is a Map ...
    List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);

    if (sentences != null && sentences.size() > 0) {
      CoreMap sentence = sentences.get(0);
      Tree tree = sentence.get(TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation.class);
      out.println();
      out.println("The first sentence parsed is:");
      tree.pennPrint(out);
    }
  }

}
```

But it doesn't work. Running the full pipeline, I'm getting the following errors through the console:

```
Reading the model of the lemmatizer
java.io.FileNotFoundException: models\lemmatizer.model (The system cannot      find the path specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
at is2.lemmatizer.Lemmatizer.readModel(Lemmatizer.java:166)
at is2.lemmatizer.Lemmatizer.<init>(Lemmatizer.java:68)
at is2.lemmatizer.Lemmatizer.<init>(Lemmatizer.java:82)
at examples.FullPipeline.main(FullPipeline.java:56)
Applying the lemmatizer
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at is2.lemmatizer.Lemmatizer.lemmatize(Lemmatizer.java:447)
at is2.lemmatizer.Lemmatizer.apply(Lemmatizer.java:530)
at examples.FullPipeline.main(FullPipeline.java:59)
```

Would somebody suggest how to correct this, please?

Comment: Please provide more information than "it doesn't work." Is there a crash? What output do you see? [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @JonGauthier: Thanks for your reply.
I added Eclipse console errors to my initial post.
Many thanks by advance for your suggestions.

Comment: This is not a Stanford CoreNLP error. From the package name, it looks like that stack trace is coming from the Mate Tools lemmatizer. Are you using this lemmatizer elsewhere in your code?

Comment: @JonGauthier: No, I’m using CoreNlp programs only so far.  I’m newbie to Stanford NLP, and just learning by example. 
Also, let me ask you, plz, something that didn’t receive attention on this Forum, perhaps because of its inconsistency:  how to get the semantic parser results in numeric form, as a matrix of digits for nodes and edges?

Comment: You are surely mistaken.. look at line 56 of your `FullPipeline.java`. There you are calling the `Lemmatizer` class, which is not from the CoreNLP package — this comes from Mate Tools.

Comment: @JonGauthier: i noticed this Lemmatizer but i was convinced it makes part of the CoreNLP package. When i mount this project, i just used  NLP package only with Eclipse, nothing also. i don't understand how this Mate Tool's lemmatizer intruded in. Though on the same Eclipse stack there is a previously built DKPRO-GPL (1.5.0)  How to get rid off this Lemmatizer? Thank you.