# Set options in Stanford CoreNLP tokenizer

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I adapted Prof. Mannings code sample from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832490/stanford-core-nlp-java-output) to read in a file, tokenize, part-of-speech-tag, and lemmatize it.

Now I came across the issue of untokenizable characters, and I would like to use the "untokenizable" option and set it to "noneKeep".

Other questions on StackOverflow explain that I would need to instantiate the tokenizer myself. However, I am not sure how to do that so that the following tasks (POS tagging etc.) are still performed as needed. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
// expects two command line parameters: one file to be read, one to write to

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import edu.stanford.nlp.io.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;

public class StanfordCoreNlpDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter out;
    out = new PrintWriter(args[1]);

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    Annotation annotation;
    annotation = new Annotation(IOUtils.slurpFileNoExceptions(args[0]));

    pipeline.annotate(annotation);
    pipeline.prettyPrint(annotation, out);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your code:

`props.setProperty("tokenize.options", "untokenizable=allKeep");`

The 6 options for untokenizable are:

`noneDelete, firstDelete, allDelete, noneKeep, firstKeep, allKeep`

Comment: Is there a full written list of configuration options that we can set from the java API?